# How to connect sql server with Objective-c login view

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been searched for the web many days the solution about this, but I don't find nothing, I find only a lot of post trying give a solution but none post serve me.
Specifically I need to do a login View which connect to a SQL Server and check if exist the user with the particular password.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a connect to sql server directly or want to post to API server so you can login ?

Comment: I want connect to sql server directly @VarunNaharia

Comment: Simply google it, you will find your answer.

Comment: please post some code what have you tried till to achieve this and what error are you getting

Comment: i am relatively new in Objective-c and now I don't have any code to connect with sql server because I don't know what I have to put, because in Google only have be examples to do a sql consult and show the info and I don't want show the info, I only want connect to SQL Server and check if the user and the password exists. @VarunNaharia